# Are C++11 containers supported by Cython?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, cython, std

Cython gives us an easy way to import C++ standard library data structures, e.g.:

```
  from libcpp.vector cimport vector
    from libcpp.utility cimport pair
```

But what about newer containers introduced with C++11: `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_set` etc. Are they supported in the same way? I could not find the appropriate import statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Cython doesn't support them by default, but you could probably create your own interface, following the structure of https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/map.pxd.</del>

Cython now supported unordered_map and unordered_set since [0.20.2](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#0202-2014-06-16).

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
from libcpp.unordered_set cimport unordered_set
```

Comment: This answer was probably correct at the time, but is now outdated.

Answer (score 22):

Current cython versions allow them.

Make sure your `setup.py` contains something like:

```
ext_module = Extension(
    "foo",
    ["foo.pyx"],
    language="c++",
    extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
    extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"]
)
```

You can then use

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
```

like for any other STL class.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with (the now current) Cython: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:554: UserWarning: got unknown compilation options, please remove: extra_link_args, extra_compile_args` (and then it fails with the C++11-related error). My setup.py looks like: `ext_modules = cythonize('x.pyx', language='c++', <options>)`.

Comment: @David You have to use the Extension() syntax, instead of specifying the parameters directly in cythonize().

Comment: I had to add "-stdlib=libc++" to the extra_compile_args to get this to work on Mac OSX 10.11.6

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, Cython version 0.29.23 it works OOTB, no extra setup needed.