# Cython: CPP dict-like map performance

Tags: c++, dictionary, cython

I've been comparing the performance of using c++ maps that imitate python dictionaries to using ordinary python dictionaries in cython. I wrote a (simplified) variant of the "fast_dict" implementation in sklearn (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/fast_dict.pyx). Consistent with the comment in the fast_dict docstring, map creation is considerably slower in the cpp case, but so is the lookup (which I was expecting to be much faster).

My implementation basically looks like this (largely lifted from the sklearn implementation, but modified to involve a map from Int->Int):

```
from libcpp.map cimport map as cpp_map
from cython.operator cimport derefernce as deref

cdef class IntDict:

    def __init__(self,dict orig_dict={}):
        """loads from an ordinary dict directly"""
        for key,val in orig_dict.iteritems():
            self.my_map[key] = val

    def __setitem__(self, int key, int value):
        self.my_map[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, int key):
        cdef cpp_map[ITYPE_t,ITYPE_t].iterator it = self.my_map.find(key)
        if it == self.my_map.end():
            raise KeyError('%d' % key)
        return deref(it).second
```

The .pxd file looks like this (again, largely from sklearn):

```
DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

ITYPE = np.intp
ctypedef np.intp_t ITYPE_t

cdef class IntDict:
    cdef cpp_map[ITYPE_t,ITYPE_t] my_mapenter
```

Here are the tests that I devised:

```
cpdef load_ord_dict(r=100000):
    cdef dict d = {}
    cdef int i,size = len(range(r))

    for i in range(size):
        d[i] = 0

    return d

cpdef load_cpp(r=100000):
    cdef IntDict d = IntDict()
    cdef int i,size = len(range(r))

    for i in range(size):
        d[i] = 0

    return d

cpdef lookup_ord(dict d,r=100000):
    cdef int i,size = len(range(r))

    for i in range(size):
       d[i]

cpdef lookup_cpp(IntDict d,r=100000):
    cdef int i,size = len(range(r))

    for i in range(size):
       d[i]
```

And the results (testing on a linux machine, the results were similar on my mac):

```
In [3]: timeit(load_ord_dict())
100 loops, best of 3: 4.3 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit(load_cpp())
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop

In [5]: d1 = load_ord_dict()

In [6]: timeit(lookup_ord(d1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.95 ms per loop

In [7]: d2 = load_cpp()

In [8]: timeit(lookup_cpp(d2))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ms per loop
```

Any thoughts about why the cpp version is so slow? Am I doing something wrong here?

UPDATE: I added the same test for an unordered_map, following the suggestion below. The performance appears to be in the middle between the dict and ordered map:

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map as umap

cdef class UnOrdIntDict:

    def __init__(self,dict orig_dict={}):
        for key,val in orig_dict.iteritems():
            """exchange cpp_map[..] in pxd with umap[..] in this case"""
            self.my_map[key] = val

    def __setitem__(self, int key, int value):
        self.my_map[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self,int key):
        """I'm assuming that this works like the ordinary cpp_map"""
        cdef umap[ITYPE_t,ITYPE_t].iterator it = self.my_map.find(key)
        if it == self.my_map.end():
            raise KeyError('%d' % key)
        return deref(it).second


   cpdef load_cpp_unordered(r=100000):
       cdef UnOrdIntDict d = UnOrdIntDict()
       cdef int i,size = len(range(r))

       for i in range(size):
           d[i] = 0

       return d

   cpdef lookup_cpp_unordered(UnOrdIntDict d,r=100000):
       cdef int i,size = len(range(r))

       for i in range(size):
           d[i]
```

And the results:

```
In [3]: timeit(load_cpp_unordered())
10 loops, best of 3: 29.8 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit(lookup_cpp_unordered(d3))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.23 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think you should be using `std::unordered_map` for this case - you're not using the orderedness property of `std::map`; see my [answer on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246783/are-c11-containers-supported-by-cython).

Comment: Thanks @AmiTavory for the pointer, I will try this out. Do you think the slow performance is related to the map ordering?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I think it's a change you should do anyway.

Comment: `std::map` is essentially an RB tree, while Python dict is a hashtable (implemented in C, by the way); I expect `std::map` to be considerably slower, and `std::unordered_map` to be of comparable speed all the rest being equal.

Comment: thanks @MatteoItalia, very interesting. Does c++ have some standard hash table implementation of a map then?

Comment: @kazimir.r: `std::unordered_map` is it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia ah, I see. Do you have any ideas about why the c++ unordered map should have comparable (or in the case above, worse) performance than a python dict given that it allows static typing?

Comment: @kazimir.r: well, performance of map storage or retrieval shouldn't be particularly affected by static or dynamic typing, the only thing that is relevant is the speed of computing the hash and the various hashtable "policies", but it's all mostly type-independent (and, given that in Python almost everything is built over `dict`, they probably optimized the hell out of it). Also, a Python `dict` actually stores just pointers to objects (while C++ by default has value semantic), so Python typically has less stuff to copy around.

Comment: After trying map and `unoredered_map`, i went back to a simple `if elif else return` structure. For small set of values, it's the fastest.