# specifying libcpp.string type for __contains__ in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm implementing a cython wrapper for some C++ data structure which will have c++ strings as both keys and values.

I have the C++ methods prototyped in a pxd, for a class with templated key/value types (sorry, I've never worked with C++, only C, so I'm not sure of the right terminology, let me know if this is unclear)

I am then defining a class in a .pyx file for the ability to call from python, which wraps an instance of `my_type[string, string]`:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
cdef class MyType:
    ## This field is declared in .pxd:
    # cdef my_type[string, string]* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, f=None):
        self.thisptr = new my_type[string, string]()

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        if hasattr(arg, 'fileno'):
            self.load(arg)
        elif isinstance(arg, int):
            self.thisptr.resize(arg)
        elif isinstance(arg, str):
            with open(arg, 'rb') as f:
                self.load(f)
        elif arg is not None:
            raise ValueError("Cannot interpret argument of type %s" % type(arg))        

    def __contains__(self, string item):
        return self.thisptr.count(item) > 0
```

now, I have another .pyx script in which I am testing this functionality, in which I define a python string, assign the bytes to a C++ string, and attempt to use the `in` operator:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

def test():
    m = MyType()
    bytes_key = 'asdf'
    bytes_val = 'jkl;'
    cdef string key = bytes_key
    cdef string val = bytes_val
    m[key] = val
    print('len(): %d' % len(m))
    assert len(m) == 1, len(m)
    print('__repr__(): %r' % (m, ))
    assert key in m
```

if I comment out the last line, everything compiles and I get output

```
len(): 0
len(): 1
__repr__(): {'asdf': 'jkl;'}
```

however, with the `assert` statement included, I get the following error during compilation:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef string val = bytes_val
    m[key] = val
    print('len(): %d' % len(m))
    assert len(m) == 1, len(m)
    print('__repr__(): %r' % (m, ))
    assert key in m
              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test_internal.pyx:72:15: Invalid types for 'in' (string, MyType)
```

If I replace `libcpp.string.string` with, for example, `libc.stdint.uint16_t`, everything works fine. Looking for how to fix this. Thank you!

EDIT
To further the mystery, if I change the offending line to `assert m.__contains__(key)`, it compiles and runs fine.

However, if I then go to another directory, and cimport MyType, and try `if not my_obj.__contains__(key)` (where `key` is `cdef`'d to be a `string`), I get a runtime error, `TypeError: an integer is required`...

Comment: What is this `m` thing?  Is it an instance of your class?

Comment: Yes, editing question to reflect this.

Comment: Just to be sure, how is my_type defined? It it a map? (``from libcpp.map cimport map as my_type``) Incidentally, why do you need a special instead of a ``dict`` ? From [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695877/cython-cpp-dict-like-map-performance) it seems ``dict`` is usually the best option.

Comment: It's a google sparse hash map. In this application I don't need speed as much as I need to minimize memory footprint. See benchmarks here: http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get your code working.
I'm not sure I know where your problem comes from, though: the only time I got an error about an integer being required was when I implemented the `__setitem__` method...

However, I think modifying the function like this should do the trick:

```
def __contains__(MyType self, item):
    if not isinstance(item, bytes):
        item = bytes(item, "UTF-8")
    return (self.thisptr.count(item) > 0)
```

In python 3 there is a difference between `str` and `bytes` (the former cannot be converted to c++ `string`) so you need to be careful about the conversion: asking for `string` type in the argument is probably going to bother you more than anything.

If this is not enough, here is a mwe:

`decl.pxd`

```
from libcpp.map cimport map as my_type
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef class MyType:
   cdef my_type[string, string]* thisptr
```

`decl.pyx`

```
cdef class MyType:

    def __cinit__(MyType self, arg=None):
        self.thisptr = new my_type[string, string]()     

    def __contains__(MyType self, item):
        if not isinstance(item, bytes):
            item = bytes(item, "UTF-8")
        return (self.thisptr.count(item) > 0)

    def __setitem__(MyType self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, bytes):
            key = bytes(key, "UTF-8")
        if not isinstance(value, bytes):
            value = bytes(value, "UTF-8")
        self.thisptr[0][key] = value

    def __len__(MyType self):
       return self.thisptr.size()
```

**EDIT:** the `setup.py` (I renamed `test.pyx` to `ctest.pyx`)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      package_data = { '': ['*.pxd'] },
      ext_modules = [
         Extension("ctest",
                   ["ctest.pyx"],
                   language='c++',
                   include_dir=["."]),
         Extension("decl",
                   ["decl.pyx"],
                   language='c++',
                   include_dir=["."])]
)
```

**EDIT2:** and of course, I forgot to notify you, but you should not use a c++ `string` as the key:

```
key1 = b'asdf'
key2 = 'asdf'
assert key1 in m
assert key2 in m
```

Comment: Sigh, unfortunately, I could not replicate this working on my machine, even using libcpp.unordered_map...

Comment: Ok, this is weird... are you sure your cython version is up-to-date? Mine is 0.24. Can you post the error message? By the way, how are you compiling the files? (I edited the answer to add my setup.py) **EDIT** ow, I just remembered! You need to use a standard python ``str`` or ``byte`` as the key in the assertion!

Comment: got it working! That's right, python wanted a python object in the assertion, not a `cdef string` conversion of a python bytes object. Which goes against my previous intuition but is good to know. Thanks for all your help, wouldn't have gotten this without it!